# Sender Profiles not selectable in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, send-definition

Can you please let me know how to mark sender address as sendable?

I have created new sender profile with new from address and it is verified already.

Comment: Could you confirm that in the From Address tab, the subdomains have been created as 'Sendable'?

Comment: Are you referring the sender profile you are referring is the one in this screenshot? ..Message configuration for the Email activity in Journey builder... https://pasteboard.co/IXwzdKE.png